# How to upgrade facebook-sdk-unity

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I need to upgrade facebook sdk for unity . Can you please suggest how to do this . I am looking to upgrade it to latest Beta which is 7.0.3

Answer (score 0):

A quick search would have granted you this result:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/upgrading-7.x